run_scaled does not bring up my scaled xterm
I want to upscale an old X application using bitmaps and bitmapped fonts.
I've found that xpra contains a run_scaled Python program that looked the right thing to use, so I installed xpra on my Suse Tumbleweed (version 6.2.0) and moved on to do a test
$ run_scaled --scale=120% --daemon=no --html=off --video=no --webcam=no -- xterm
2024-08-25 22:33:08,998 Error: cannot enable SSH socket upgrades
2024-08-25 22:33:08,998  `paramiko` module not found
2024-08-25 22:33:09,015 no uinput module (not usually needed)
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
2024-08-25 22:33:10,427 pointer device emulation using XTest
2024-08-25 22:33:10,432 wrote pid 456697 to '/run/user/1000/xpra/2/server.pid'
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448 cannot create group socket '/run/xpra/localhost.localdomain-2'
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448  [Errno 13] Permission denied
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448 created unix domain sockets:
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448  '/run/user/1000/xpra/localhost.localdomain-2'
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448  '/home/boffi/.xpra/localhost.localdomain-2'
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448  '/run/user/1000/xpra/2/socket'
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448 created abstract sockets:
2024-08-25 22:33:10,448  '@xpra/2'
2024-08-25 22:33:10,449 xvfb pid 456708
2024-08-25 22:33:10,469 D-Bus notification forwarding is available
2024-08-25 22:33:10,544 xpra is ready.
2024-08-25 22:33:10,545 xpra X11 seamless server version 6.2.0-r36269M (g6fcb897e) beta
2024-08-25 22:33:10,546  uid=1000 (boffi), gid=100 (users)
2024-08-25 22:33:10,546  running with pid 456697 on Linux openSUSE 20240823
2024-08-25 22:33:10,546  cpython 3.11
2024-08-25 22:33:10,550  connected to X11 display :2 with 24 bit colors

2024-08-25 22:33:10,755 Xpra GTK3 X11 client version 6.2.0-r36269M (g6fcb897e) beta
2024-08-25 22:33:10,774  running on Linux openSUSE 20240823
2024-08-25 22:33:10,774  cpython 3.11
2024-08-25 22:33:10,775  window manager is 'KWin'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,148 GStreamer version 1.24.6
2024-08-25 22:33:11,183 created unix domain sockets:
2024-08-25 22:33:11,183  '/run/user/1000/xpra/clients/localhost.localdomain-456755'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,266  keyboard settings: rules=evdev, model=pc104, layout=us
2024-08-25 22:33:11,270  desktop size is 2160x1440:
2024-08-25 22:33:11,270   :0.0 (571x381 mm - DPI: 96x96) workarea: 2160x1382
2024-08-25 22:33:11,270     BOE eDP          (296x197 mm - DPI: 185x186)
2024-08-25 22:33:11,270  upscaled to 120%, virtual screen size: 1800x1200
2024-08-25 22:33:11,270   :0.0 (571x381 mm - DPI: 80x80) workarea: 1800x1152
2024-08-25 22:33:11,270     BOE eDP          (296x197 mm - DPI: 154x155)
2024-08-25 22:33:11,288 New socket connection received
2024-08-25 22:33:11,289  on '@xpra/2'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,292 Handshake complete; enabling connection
2024-08-25 22:33:11,309  mmap is enabled using 512MB area in /run/user/1000/xpra/xpra.xwwynt_f.mmap
2024-08-25 22:33:11,310 Python/GTK3 Linux openSUSE 20240823 X11 client version 6.2
2024-08-25 22:33:11,310  OpenGL is disabled
2024-08-25 22:33:11,318 setting key repeat rate from client: 600ms delay / 40ms interval
2024-08-25 22:33:11,318 setting keymap: rules=evdev, model=pc104, layout=us, options=compose:ralt,caps:ctrlmodifier
2024-08-25 22:33:11,359  client root window size is 1800x1200
2024-08-25 22:33:11,360   :0.0 (571x381 mm - DPI: 80x80) workarea: 1800x1152
2024-08-25 22:33:11,360     BOE eDP          (296x197 mm - DPI: 154x155)
2024-08-25 22:33:11,366 enabled fast mmap transfers using 512MB shared memory area
2024-08-25 22:33:11,366 enabled remote logging
2024-08-25 22:33:11,366 Xpra X11 seamless server version 6.2
2024-08-25 22:33:11,368 client   1 @00.610 Xpra X11 seamless server version 6.2
2024-08-25 22:33:11,441 Attached to xpra server at socket://@xpra/2
2024-08-25 22:33:11,441  (press Control-C to detach)

2024-08-25 22:33:11,444 client   1 @00.685 Attached to xpra server at socket://@xpra/2
2024-08-25 22:33:11,444 client   1 @00.685  (press Control-C to detach)
2024-08-25 22:33:11,448 running
2024-08-25 22:33:11,449 client   1 @00.692 running
2024-08-25 22:33:11,483 Warning: the python netifaces package is missing
2024-08-25 22:33:11,483  some networking functionality will be unavailable
2024-08-25 22:33:11,485 setting keymap: rules=evdev, model=pc104, layout=us, options=compose:ralt,caps:ctrlmodifier
2024-08-25 22:33:11,806 printer forwarding enabled using postscript and pdf
2024-08-25 22:33:11,807 15.0GB of system memory
2024-08-25 22:33:11,815 started command `xterm` with pid 456833
2024-08-25 22:33:11,816 wrote pid 456833 to '/run/user/1000/xpra/2/xterm.pid'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,818 started command `ibus-daemon` with pid 456834
2024-08-25 22:33:11,820 child 'xterm' with pid 456833 has terminated
2024-08-25 22:33:11,820 all children have exited and --exit-with-children was specified, exiting
2024-08-25 22:33:11,820 X11 seamless server is terminating
2024-08-25 22:33:11,820 Disconnecting client @xpra/2:
2024-08-25 22:33:11,820  server shutdown
2024-08-25 22:33:11,821 Python/GTK3 client 1 disconnected.
2024-08-25 22:33:11,825 server requested disconnect:
2024-08-25 22:33:11,825  server shutdown
2024-08-25 22:33:11,830 removing unix domain socket '/run/user/1000/xpra/localhost.localdomain-2'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,830 removing unix domain socket '/home/boffi/.xpra/localhost.localdomain-2'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,830 removing unix domain socket '/run/user/1000/xpra/2/socket'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,830 removing abstract socket '@xpra/2'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,831 killing xvfb with pid 456708
XIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server ":2"
      after 13 requests (13 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
/usr/lib64/python3.11/subprocess.py:1127: ResourceWarning: subprocess 456755 is still running
  _warn("subprocess %s is still running" % self.pid,
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2024-08-25 22:33:11,839 session directory '/run/user/1000/xpra/2' was not removed
2024-08-25 22:33:11,840  because it still contains some files:
2024-08-25 22:33:11,840  'ibus-daemon.pid'
22:33 Sun, Aug 25 ~/ $ 2024-08-25 22:33:11,964 removing unix domain socket '/run/user/1000/xpra/clients/localhost.localdomain-456755'

As you can see, the xterm is started and terminates immediately
2024-08-25 22:33:11,815 started command `xterm` with pid 456833
2024-08-25 22:33:11,816 wrote pid 456833 to '/run/user/1000/xpra/2/xterm.pid'
2024-08-25 22:33:11,818 started command `ibus-daemon` with pid 456834
2024-08-25 22:33:11,820 child 'xterm' with pid 456833 has terminated

and the server is shut down.
Just for confirmation, I used the command
$ run_scaled ... -- xterm -e /usr/bin/bash -c read

but the xterm process terminated anyhow.
Am I missing something or there is a problem?

(1) So, are you saying that xterm fails even when not run with run_scaled?  Doesn’t that suggest that run_scaled is not the problem?  (2) Are you really saying “/us/bin/bash”?  Because that is an obvious error.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' No, at least in my intention  I did not say that, but I said that I tried to run run_scaled with a different argument, with the intention of preventing the terminal to close itself. And of course /us/bin/bash was a typo in writing the question.

Side note, you can scale up bdf fonts with bdfresize if that is an alternative solution.

@meuh Unfortunately XFig author dimensioned the various buttons in pixels, just to contain their text in the specified, (now) minuscule font, and if you specify larger fonts using the xresources mechanism, the text is larger than the button and it's truncated. Alas, it's necessary to scale the whole window…
